# C# Swashbuckle.Net45 didn't show controllers on Swagger UI

Tags: c#, web, swagger, swashbuckle, .net-4.6

I have add Swashbuckle.Net45 (Swagger) to my C# (.NET 4.6) 2 different web projects. on one everything working great on another I don't see any controller on Swagger-UI.

as I know the configuration must be very easy.

"Swashbuckle.Net45" config file

[image]

My Controller

[image]

Swagger-UI

[image]

what have I have missed?

Comment: You should use text instead of images

Comment: It's impossible to read those images, much less copy, google or execute them.  The swagger configuration is missing entirely, only the comments appear. Post code as *code*, not images of the code

Comment: The "controller" isn't a controller either. It doesn't inherit from Controller or ControllerBase. Does the project run at all?

Answer (score 0):

A common Error is when you create your Controller File as a class instead of Mvc-/API-Controller file. Even though the code is the same, it won't work.

And make sure you add the Controllers in the startup.cs/program.cs.
Example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    //or
    services.AddMvc();
}
```